# Linux: lightweight pdf reader which can bookmark where I left off reading?

Tags: linux, software-rec, pdf, pdf-reader, lightweight

I am using [Arch Linux](http://www.archlinux.org/) on a notebook, which has a 4GB SSD drive. so I have to save disk space/storage by any possible means.

Reading technological PDFs are really painful when you have to memorize daily reading progress.

I have tried epdfview/xpdf/Foxit Reader, they are lightweight enough, but not able to keep my reading progress.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

KDE's [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) saves reading position, although I'm not sure if you consider it "lightweight".

Answer (score 1):

Both [apvlv](http://code.google.com/p/apvlv/) and [Zathura](http://pwmt.org/projects/zathura) have bookmark features, and are lighter weight than either evince or okular.

Comment: 1 vote for Zathura, jumanji is a very good browser created by them :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at evince? The bookmark feature is not noted in the features however, mine marks my place every time I close it. 
I wonder why you couldn't either offload some baggage to a flash drive or boot from a flash drive?